# Which of the following gives an ideal version of vector e

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Can someone please explain this to me? My midterm is literally in 7 hours and I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to transform the masses into forces, by multiplying with the gravitational acceleration.
2. Once you found $f(e)$ at previous part, subtract $b$, then divide by $k$
3. Check which answer is the correct one

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that... Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Just accept the solution

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this website. I didn't know I had to. It's done :)